# Can't get setTimeout in javascript to work properly

Tags: javascript

I have a function in javascript:

```
function test(){
...
    if (){
        setTimeout(test(), 1000);
    }
}
```

according to the manual, i can call this with:

```
setTimeout(test(), 1000);
```

in fact, it calls, but do not wait the 1s. so I try to use it like the following and it works.

```
setTimeout(function(){test();}, 1000);
```

Anyone can explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling with

```
setTimeout(test, 1000);
```

and NOT with

```
setTimeout(test(), 1000);
```

In other words, the function you want to call after 1000 ms is test, not the result of calling test!

The reason why

```
setTimeout(function(){test();}, 1000);
```

works is that the function you call after 1000ms is a function that calls test, which is basically `test` itself.  For lambda calculus geeks, that's called eta-reduction.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination.

Answer (score 3):

Which manual? Calling `test()` would call things returned by `test()` and pass it to `setTimeout`, so unless your `test()` is returning a function, this won't work.

You could use the anon function alternative, or you can pass it like `setTimeout(test, 1000)` without the `()`.

Another bad usage you might find along the way is to pass it as string like:

`setTimeout("test()", 1000)`

avoid this at all cost, as this is equivalent to calling `eval` and you'll run into scoping issue sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` expects a function reference. When you pass it this:

```
setTimeout(test(), 1000);
```

That is passing the *result* of calling the `test` function to `setTimeout`. Instead, pass it the reference to test itself:

`setTimeout(test, 1000);`

Want to see something fancy?

```
function test () {
    var what_are_you = 'a closure';
    return function () {
       alert('I am '+what_are_you+'!')
    }
}
setTimeout(test(), 1000);
```

Here, I am returning a function reference from a function call. See the article below for more info on that!

**Documentation**

- `setTimeout` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout
- Article about functions, function references - http://jszen.blogspot.com/2008/07/function-reference-vs-function-call.html